# why did the 0 delete it the other part of the string?

Tags: c

I really didn't understand why does the " u'est " get deleted ?

```
 int main()
{
 char dieser[15] = "Stan nu'est" ;
            dieser[6] = 0;
            printf(dieser);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `0` is the terminal character, printf will print strings only up to it, so nothing is actually deleted, only not printed

Comment: Do you know how `printf` determines how many characters to print?

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
dieser[6] = 0;
```

You're assigning a value of **0** to that character. This value is mapped to the ASCII table when the program is printing the string to the screen.

If you look at the [ASCII table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) you'll see that the character with **0** value is `NUL` which is the *null terminator*. It indicates the end of a string.

So what's happening is: you're inserting a string terminator character in the middle of your string. When the **printf** function is reading the string it finds that character and stops. That's how you end up with that cut string.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks L.F.! 
I really look forward to being part of this great community!

Answer (score 0):

Actually your string isn't really deleted. The value 0 (or '\0') indicates the end of your string. So printf stops print your string when finds the first 0.
If you change your code do:

```
int main()
{
 char dieser[15] = "Stan nu'est" ;
            dieser[6] = 0;
            printf(dieser);
            printf(&dieser[7]);
return 0;
}
```

You will see "Stan n'est" in your console. It means, your string continues on memory, but you have '\0' instead of 'u' on position 6 of your string.